# A proof with Legendre polynomials and an integral minimum value

Tags: functional-analysis

I need to prove that, over the monic polynomials $f$ of degree $n$, the integral $$\int_{-1}^1\bigl(f(x)\bigr)^2\,dx$$ takes its minimum value when $$f(x)=\frac{2^n}{\binom{2n}n}L_n(x),$$ where $L_n(x)$ is the $n$th Legendre polynomial.

Comment: What do you mean by "an is the reciprocal of the leading coefficient of Ln(x)"?, in the proof it self?
Your result is not what I want to prove, it's upside down, it should be the inverse value right?

Comment: In my answer, I am using $a_n$ to denote the coefficient in front of $L_n(x)$ in the expansion of $f(x)$ as I write in the first bullet point in my answer. In order for $a_nL_n(x)$ to be **monic**, $a_n$ must be the reciprocal of the leading coefficient of $L_n(x)$.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you are either granted use of or can independently verify these facts:

- The Legendre polynomials form a basis for the space of polynomials, so we may write $$f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n a_kL_k(x)$$ for some real numbers $a_k\in\bf R$, for any $f(x)$ of degree $n$.
- If $f(x)$ is monic, then $a_n$ is the reciprocal of the leading coefficient of $L_n(x)$. Looks like that means you have to verify that the leading coefficient of $L_n(x)$ is $2^{-n}{2n\choose n}$.
- The Legendre polynomials are orthogonal, in the sense that $$\langle L_r,L_s\rangle=\int_{-1}^{+1}L_r(x)L_s(x)dx=0$$ when $r\ne s$. Therefore (with $\|\cdot\|$ induced from $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ defined directly above) $$\|f(x)\|^2=\sum_{k=0}^na_k^2\|L_k(x)\|^2\ge a_n^2\|L_n(x)\|^2$$ with equality if and only if $a_0=a_1=a_2=\cdots=a_{n-1}=0$.

Comment: I really understood the idea of this proof but I've been working around with fourier coificients and  all that's to get to the final result, verify that the leading coeficient of Ln(x) is that number. Does anyone help me out on that a little bit more?? Thanks

Comment: @deiota: Do you have [Rodrigues formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_formula) available to you?

Comment: Yes, it's[url]http://s2.postimg.org/4nnf7cwqx/image.jpg[/URL]

Comment: @deiota Indeed. If you expand $(x^2-1)^n$ with the binomial expansion the leading term is $x^{2n}$; if you differentiate that $n$ times the leading coefficient is ... ?

Comment: HI got to the expansion expression with the leading term x^2n and th constant (-1)^n, I suppose the leading coeficient you asked me about is n. I'm I correct? Or (-1)^n..

Comment: I'm pretty confused since tried to differentiate the expansion expression and it gave me a strange result. That's why I'm not sure what the result is!

Comment: I hate when I can't finish an e exercise specially when I have to finish it for tomorrow.

Comment: @deiota: If you differentiate $x^{2n}$ once you get $2nx^{2n-1}$. If you differentiate it again you get $2n(2n-1)x^{2n-2}$. And differentiate it again you get $2n(2n-1)(2n-2)x^{2n-3}$. If you differentiate it a total of $n$ times, you will get $2n(2n-1)\cdots(n+1)x^n$, and if you divide that leading coefficient $2n(2n-1)\cdots(n+1)$ by $2^nn!$ (the factor in the Rodrigues formula), the value is $$\frac{2n(2n-1)\cdots(n+1)}{2^nn!}=2^{-n}{2n\choose n}.$$

Comment: Responding your comment posted as an answer and now deleted, @deiota: In my answer, I am using $a_n$ to denote the coefficient in front of $L_n(x)$ in the expansion of $f(x)$ as I write in the first bullet point in my answer. I am not using it to refer to the leading coefficient of $L_n(x)$ itself. In order for $a_nL_n(x)$ to be **monic** as prescribed by the hypotheses, $a_n$ must be the reciprocal of the leading coefficient of $L_n(x)$. You have $a_n=2^n/{2n\choose n}$ in your question, so we sought to show the leading coefficient of $L_n(x)$ was $2^{-n}{2n\choose n}$ (and succeeded).