# Find min of $\int_{-1}^1| x^3-a-bx-cx^2|^2 dx$ and max of $\int_{-1}^1 x^3 g(x) dx$

Tags: maxima-minima, integral-inequality

> 1) Apply best approximation theorem to compute min$\int_{-1}^1| x^3-a-bx-cx^2|^2 dx$.
>
> 2) Find max $\int_{-1}^1 x^3 g(x) dx$, where $g$ is subject to the constraints 
>   $$\int_{-1}^1 g(x)dx = \int_{-1}^1xg(x)dx=\int_{-1}^1 x^2 g(x) dx=0,\quad\text{and}\quad \int_{-1}^1|g(x)|^2 dx=1.$$

I don't know how to start to solve this problem, anyone can help me.

Comment: Robert Z They aren't unrelated. You can use the result of the first question to answer the second.

Comment: Use the theorem of projection on the $span\{1,x,x^2\}$ in $L^2(-1,1)$

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/336182/a-proof-with-legendre-polynomials-and-an-integral-minimum-value

Comment: @Professor Vector Thanks for your enlightening comment!

Comment: @Robert Z You're welcome. In fact, my comment was a bit obscure, due to lack of time, but I had in mind Cauchy-Schwartz, indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Hint for 1). Since $\int_{-1}^1x^d dx=0$ when $d$ is odd, and $\int_{-1}^1x^d dx=\frac{2}{d+1}$ when $d$ is even, by expanding the square we get
$$\int_{-1}^1(x^3-a-bx-cx^2)^2 dx
=\frac{2}{3}b^2-\frac{4}{5}b+\frac{2}{7}+2a^2+\frac{4}{3}ac+\frac{2}{5}c^2\\
=\frac{2}{3}\left(b-\frac{3}{5}\right)^2+\frac{8}{175}+2\left(a^2+\frac{2}{3}ac+\frac{1}{5}c^2\right).
$$
Moreover $(1/3)^2-1/5<0$ implies that $\left(a^2+\frac{2}{3}ac+\frac{1}{5}c^2\right)\geq 0$.

Hint for 2) (see Professor Vector's comment). By the given constraints and the [Cauchy-Schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality),
$$\begin{align}
\int_{-1}^1 x^3 g(x) dx&=\int_{-1}^1 (x^3-a-bx-cx^2)g(x) dx\\
&\leq
\left(\int_{-1}^1 (x^3-a-bx-cx^2)^2dx\right)^{1/2}
\left(\int_{-1}^1 (g(x))^2dx\right)^{1/2}\\
&\leq
\left(\int_{-1}^1 (x^3-a-bx-cx^2)^2dx\right)^{1/2}.
\end{align}$$
Hence the maximum of the LHS is less or equal to the minimum of the RHS (see 1)).

Comment: @J. Klins Any progress towards the solution?